# Resolve two related arrays in by value of "child" entry

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two PHP arrays of clients and contacts.
Every contact belongs to a client.
Not all clients have contacts.

The "parent" array is `clients`. But the information about the relation is in the "child" data, `contacts`.

```
$clients = array(
    1 => array(
      'id' => 123, 
      'name' => 'Client 1'
    ),
    2 => array(
      'id' => 234, 
      'name' => 'Client 2'
    )
 );

$contacts = array(
    1 => array(
      'id' => 345, 
      'name' => 'John',
      'client' => array(
         'id' = 123
      )
    ),
    2 => array(
      'id' => 567, 
      'name' => 'Doe',
      'client' => array(
         'id' = 123
      )
    ),
 );
```

John & Doe are related to Client 1 with the id 123.
Client 2 has no contacts.

I would like to retrieve the following `$addresses` from these arrays:

```
Client 1
John

Client 1
Doe

Client 2
```

What I've come up now is this, which works but is still slow:

```
    foreach ($clients as $clientData) {
        // find out if it's a client with or without contacts
        $client_has_contact = false;
        foreach ($contacts as $contactData) {
            if ($contactData['client']['id'] && ($contactData['client']['id'] == $clientData['id'])) {
                // do the work
                $address->save();
                $client_has_contact = true;
            }
        }
        // if client doesn't have a contact
        if(!$client_has_contact){
            // do the work
            $address->save();
        }
    }
```

How do I *efficiently* resolve those two arrays?
I just can't wrap my head around that.

PS if there are any Laravel `Arr::` helpers the could be used to do it quicker that would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Collections

You could use the `contains` method of the Collection class to see if the Collection has an item with a particular value for a field:

```
$contacts = collect($contacts);

foreach ($clients as $client) {
    if ($contacts->contains('client.id', $client['id']) {
        // client has contacts
    } else {
        // client does not have contacts
    }
}
```

You could also `pluck` all the 'client.id' values from the array, then check against that single set of values to see if it contains the client id of the client you are currently iterating:

```
$list = collect($contacts)->pluck('client.id');
...
if ($list->contains($client['id'])) {
   // client has contacts
}
```

Or if you want to search that list as an array with `in_array`:

```
$list = collect($contacts)->pluck('client.id')->toArray();
...
if (in_array($client['id'], $list)) {
    // client has contacts
}
```

You could also group the `$contacts` by the `client.id` value using Collections. You can then see if the group exists for that 'id':

```
$groups = collect($contacts)->groupBy('client.id');

foreach ($clients as $client) {
    if ($groups->has($client['id'])) {
        // client has contacts
    } else {
        // client does not have contacts
    }
}
```

A few quick options.

#### Using the `Arr` helper

The `Arr` helper class has a `pluck` method:

```
$list = Arr::pluck($contacts, 'client.id');
...
if (in_array($client['id'], $list) {
    // client has contacts
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains) - `contains`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) - `pluck`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) - `groupBy`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-has) - `has`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Helpers - Available Methods - Array & Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-pluck) - `pluck`

[PHP.net Manual - Function Reference - Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - `in_array`